# code throwing a warning even with correct generic type?

Tags: java

Why is this code throwing error, even though the method returns the correct generic type?

```
public class test { 

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Box<Integer> bi;  // bi declared of the type box<Integer>

        bi = createBox(); // create box returns object of type box<Integer> 
    }

    static Box createBox(){

        return new Box<Integer>();
    }

}

class Box<t> {
}
```

Why is it throwing a warning?

Thanks

Comment: `Box createBox()` method is *declared* using raw type of `Box`.

Comment: return type of `createBox()` method is of raw. make it specific, `Box<Integer>`, or `Box<?>`